# Run crontab for php script - path

Tags: ubuntu, cron

crontab -e:

```
*/2 * * * * php /var/www/example/JedEszErHi0gJQU7ya.php
```

Why this doesn't work?

I get in log files:

syslog

```
Mar 14 20:10:01 example CRON[4721]: (root) CMD (php /var/www/example/JedEszErHi0gJQU7ya.php)
```

What I do wrong? Path to file is incorrect?

Comment: Try `echo "$PATH"` in your terminal, and then at the top of the cron script, add `PATH= # what echo printed here`

Comment: echo give me: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games ... putting it in top cron doesn't change anything

Comment: In that case it's more than likely an issue with the php file itself. Try what JohnFF said

Comment: when i add */2 * * * * https://example.com/JedEszErHi0gJQU7ya.php - it works

Comment: So the correct path to the php file is that, not what you had in the question

Answer (score 0):

How it isn't working is quite unclear. I'd have thought it would work, given it appears in syslog.

Try the following:

1. Look in your PHP logs (/var/log).
2. Run the PHP file in the command line outside cron and see whether an error occurs.